# Perl how to read a line from a file handle that is an array element

Tags: perl, file-io

My perl script takes any number of files, opens them, and reads one line from each.  But it's not working.  Here's my code.

```
#!/bin/perl
$numfile = scalar @ARGV;

for ($i = 0; $i < $numfile; ++$i)
{
    open $fh[$i],"<",$ARGV[$i];
    $line[$i] = <$fh[$i]>;
}

for ($i = 0; $i < $numfile; ++$i) 
{ 
    print  "$i => $line[$i]"; 
}
```

Any ideas why this doesn't work?  Is it illegal to store file handles in an array?

I expect this to print the first line of each file.  Instead I get

```
0 => GLOB(0x36d190)1 =>
```

I am using perl v5.18.2

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `<>` is being interpreted as a file [`glob`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/glob.html) instead of a [`readline`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/readline.html).

Use the following to explicitly specify your intent:

```
$line[$i] = readline $fh[$i];
```

Answer (score 4):

Use `readline` instead of `<>`.

`perlop` says:

> If what's within the angle brackets is neither a filehandle nor a simple scalar variable containing a filehandle name, typeglob,
>          or typeglob reference, it is interpreted as a filename pattern to be globbed

Answer (score 3):

[Not an answer, but a comment that doesn't fit as a comment]

Always use `use strict; use warnings;`. You are severely handicapping yourself without them.

You don't need to use multiple handles since you never need more than one at a time.

Some other cleanups:

```
#!/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

my @first_lines;

for my $qfn (@ARGV)
{
    open(my $fh, '<', $qfn)
        or die("Can't open $qfn: $!\n");

    push @first_lines, scalar( <$fh> );
}

for my $i (0..$#first_lines)
{ 
    print  "$i => $first_lines[$i]"; 
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the advice about strict/warning! I will start using them now. This snippet is part of a larger script, the purpose of which is to merge/sort several files. I have dozens of files, and each is over 100 Mb. I sort each file individually. Then I read the first line of each file, and then I chose the "lowest" line, print it, and then read the next line from that file, and repeat until all lines are printed.